# monitor the amount of requests openstack4j does

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, openstack4j

Jenkins's openstack-plugin uses openstack4j for talking to an openstack cloud. I'm looking for a way that we can we can monitor the amount of http(s) API calls openstack4j does, from client side perspective.

Some possible things to know:

- Jenkins can tell me that? (although I believe openstack4j does the http(s) call independently)
- it's running inside a container, some https call monitoring tools that I could use on that level?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions:

1. I don't think Jenkins can do this monitoring for you, in the end, it's just a big, distributed, job scheduler and runner. If there's no plugin purposefully written for this, it can't. You'd have to write it yourself.
2. Regarding the monitoring, there's a bunch of questions to answer, actually:

   - Do you want just a Java based solution?

     Surprisingly, I couldn't find anything Java based, the standard Java Management Extensions (JMX) apparently do not have direct support for investigating a process' open network connections.

     If it doesn't have to be Java-specific, you could use [tcpdump](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/) or [tshark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4494489/1320143) to analyze the traffic, as long as you know where the calls go, for example.

     Another generic Linux based alternative is to launch the process through [strace](https://gist.github.com/graste/929bb122c353bdd90c20). You might need to make some [adjustments for Java](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2009/01/how-to-use-strace-with-java/).
   - Is the connection HTTP or HTTPS (it matters a lot)?

     For HTTPS one option would be to man-in-the-middle the HTTPS connection with some sort of proxy. Then you can just check the logs of the proxy for the connections

Comment: HTTPS, and tcpcump or strace or way to generic, I would like on API level metrics on calls made to certain apis, with latency numbers, ...

Comment: I don’t know of any off the shelf solution for stuff like this, unfortunately :(